# How to make a query to display?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
recipe
+----------+---------+
| recipe_id|     name|
+----------+---------+
|         1|   name_1|
+----------+---------+
|         2|   name_2|
+----------+---------+
|         3|   name_3|
+----------+---------+

ingredient
+--------------+---------+
| ingredient_id|     name|
+--------------+---------+
|             7|   cheese|
+--------------+---------+
|             9|   pepper|
+--------------+---------+
|            16|   tomato|
+--------------+---------+

recipe_ingredient
+----------+---------------+
| recipe_id|  ingredient_id|
+----------+---------------+
|         1|              7|
+----------+---------------+
|         1|             16|
+----------+---------------+
|         2|              7|
+----------+---------------+
|         3|              7|
+----------+---------------+
|         3|              9|
+----------+---------------+
|         3|             16|
+----------+---------------+
```

how to display only those recipes in which the ingredients are strictly identical?
I use it

```
SELECT r.name, r.recipe_id
  FROM recipe AS r
    LEFT JOIN recipe_ingredient AS r_i ON r_i.ingredient_id = '7'
                 OR r_i.ingredient_id = '16'
WHERE r.recipe_id=r_i.recipe_id
```

but it does not work as I need to.In the end, I want to get this result.

```
+----------+---------------+
|      name|      recipe_id|
+----------+---------------+
|    name_1|              1|
+----------+---------------+
|    name_3|              3|
+----------+---------------+
```

help please

P.S: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Recipe number 1 does not have identical ingredients.

Comment: He means identical to the list of ingredients he's checking for, which are 7 and 16 in this example.

Comment: Please add the output that you got with your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `r`.`recipe_id`, `r`.`name`
    FROM `recipe` `r` 
    JOIN ( SELECT `r_i`.`recipe_id`
           FROM `recipe_ingredient` `r_i`
           WHERE `r_i`.`ingredient_id` IN ( 7,16 )
           GROUP BY `r_i`.`recipe_id`
           HAVING COUNT(`recipe_id`) >= 2
    ) `result` ON `r`.`recipe_id` = `result`.`recipe_id`
```

example:

```
$ingred_arr = array(7,16);
$count_ingred = count($ingred_arr);

$query = "
    SELECT `r`.`recipe_id`, `r`.`name`
    FROM `recipe` `r` 
    JOIN ( SELECT `r_i`.`recipe_id`
           FROM `recipe_ingredient` `r_i`
           WHERE `r_i`.`ingredient_id` IN ( ".implode(',',$ingred_arr)." )
           GROUP BY `r_i`.`recipe_id`
           HAVING COUNT(`recipe_id`) >= ".$count_ingred."
    ) `result` ON `r`.`recipe_id` = `result`.`recipe_id` "
```

result:

```
+----------+---------------+
|      name|      recipe_id|
+----------+---------------+
|    name_1|              1|
+----------+---------------+
|    name_3|              3|
+----------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.name, r.recipe_id
FROM recipe AS r
JOIN (SELECT recipe_id,
             COUNT(*) c AS total_ingredients,
             SUM(ingredient_id IN (7, 16)) AS matching_ingredients
      FROM recipe_ingredient
      GROUP BY recipe_id
      HAVING total_ingredients = 2 AND matching_ingredients = 2) AS r_i
ON r.recipe_id = r_i.recipe_id
```

In general, the values in the `HAVING` clause should be the number of ingredients in the `IN` clause.

Comment: this is not exactly what I need, because I do not know how much of each ingredient in the recipe.
can I add another column to the table?

`HAVING total_ingredients = r.count_ingredients AND matching_ingredients = 2`

whether it will work fast if I have 25,000 recipes?

Comment: You can add a `quantity` column to the `recipe_ingredient` table. My query doesn't care.

Comment: But it gets more complicated if you want to find only the recipes that need 4 tomatoes and 3 slices of cheese.

Comment: You misunderstood me =) 
I want to do a simple search by ingredients.