# SQL searching for all subsets

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to create a recipe search query that returns recipes that can be made using only the ingredients that the user already has. For instance, if the user has onions, tomatos, milk, lettuce, chocolate syrup, etc. then the query should result in recipes like salad (onions, tomato, lettuce), chocolate milk (milk, chocolate syrup), etc.

Right now I have a table called recipes with columns id (primary key) and ingredients. I have another table called user_ingredients with columns id and ingredient.

What would an effective SQL query look like? In terms of set theory I know that I want all recipes where the set of ingredients is contained within the set of user ingredients. I just don't know how to translate this into SQL since I'm a bit of an SQL newbie.

Also, if you think my database structure isn't what it should be, feel free to recommend something better!

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007709/how-to-make-a-query-to-display/20007818#20007818 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007709/how-to-make-a-query-to-display/20007818#20007818 ? If you search SO for questions about recipes, you'll probably find many similar.

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific database you're using: mysql, sql-server, oracle, etc.

Comment: If you already know set theory then you should understand SQL because it uses same concepts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

How do you store multiple ingredients in recipes.ingredients column? You should have another table for this - recipe_ingredients with one row per each ingredient of each recipe.

With such setup, this query is simple and should also be efficient:

```
SELECT recipe_id
  FROM recipe_ingredients ri
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
               FROM user_ingredients
              WHERE user_id = 1) ui ON (ui.ingredient = ri.ingredient)
 GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING SUM(case when user_id is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Check out the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c7c3/2)